# Does the entropy of a random variable depend only on its distribution?

Tags: random-variables, entropy

I have trouble understanding whenever or not the entropy of X a random variable is only dependent on its distribution.

I would be tempted to answer yes to this question because we use the probabilities of X taking a certain value which depends on X's distribution in order to plug them into Shannon's formula.

Am I correct?

Comment: How do you define the entropy?

Comment: As you gain information about an event the entropy decreases.